# Primeng float text on p-password not working

Tags: angular, primeng

Does primeng support float text on p-password? it is not shown in there examples and it is not working on my end with tag pInputPassword.

Answer (score 0):

i share you my code, this working for me

```
<div class="p-inputgroup">
      <span class="p-float-label">
     <p-password [toggleMask]="true" [feedback]="false" formControlName="password2" ></p-password>
     <label>Confirmar contraseña</label>
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that this solution appears to use FontAwesome icons, which aren't required for the answer.

Comment: The code is corrected and the use of fontAwasone icons is eliminated